# Specify Django Test Database names in settings.py

Tags: django, testing, settings, django-testing, django-settings

I'm specifying the databases using a python object:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default':{
   'ENGINE':'mysql',
   'NAME':'testsqldb',
   'USER':'<username>',
   'PASSWORD':'<password>',
 },
 'dynamic_data':{
   'ENGINE': 'sqlite3',
   'NAME':'',
   'USER':'',
   'PASSWORD':''
 },
}
```

How can I specify the name of my test database? I've been trying to use `TEST_NAME = 'auto_tests'` in the settings.py file. However, when I run `python manage.py tests <app_name>` I get the following message:

```
Creating test database 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_testsqldb'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_testsqldb', or 'no' to cancel:
```

I'm expecting the system to create a separate database when running my tests, presumably called 'auto_tests_testsqldb'; however, it's still asking me about test_testsqldb.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Django 1.6 and below, `TEST_NAME` should be a key of one of your database dictionaries. But in Django 1.7 and above, you use a `TEST` key which is a dictionary of settings for test databases.

You probably want:

```
DATABASES = {
 'default':{
   'ENGINE':'mysql',
   'NAME':'testsqldb',
   'USER':'<username>',
   'PASSWORD':'<password>',
   'TEST': {
       'NAME': 'auto_tests',
   }
 },
 'dynamic_data':{
   'ENGINE': 'sqlite3',
   'NAME':'',
   'USER':'',
   'PASSWORD':''
 },
}
```

Alternatively, perhaps you are wanting to use a different engine for your tests? In that case, I think you'll just have to create a separate settings file for testing. It can import from your standard settings module and override `DATABASES`.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, the TEST_NAME key is what I was looking for! Didn't think to look in the testing documentation for the settings information.

Comment: In Django 1.10 this is now `"TEST" : {"NAME" : "auto_tests"},` (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#test)