# Detect django testing mode

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm writing a reusable django app and I need to ensure that its models are only sync'ed when the app is in test mode. I've tried to use a custom DjangoTestRunner, but I found no examples of how to do that (the documentation only shows how to define a custom test runner).

EDIT

Here's how I'm doing it:

```py
#in settings.py
import sys
TEST = 'test' in sys.argv
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm here because I have the same requirement. However, I just want to point out that having your code behave differently when a test is running is a really bi NO-NO. As much as possible, you want to test the code the way it will actually work.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I think the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651002/465673 is a much cleaner way of doing it:

> Put this in your settings.py:

```
import sys

TESTING = sys.argv[1:2] == ['test']
```

Comment: Today I'm following a similar approach:

    `TEST = 'test' in sys.argv`

Same effect, but a bit more cleaner to read :-)

Comment: @jjmaestro is there any reason for not writing `TESTING = sys.argv[1] == 'test'`. I thinks it's exactly the same and simpler

Comment: @glarrain: using a slice (as in `[1:2]`) means you won't get an index out of bounds error if by change `sys.argv` has fewer than two elements in it.

Comment: @HerberthAmaral, your suggestion in the first comment should become an answer by itself.

Comment: Doesn't work when something else is running tests, like django jenkins.

Comment: This won't work if started as "./manage.py test" instead of "python manage.py test". Many developers prefer that since it's shorter.

Comment: @AlexK For "./manage.py test" , sys.argv=['./manage.py', 'test']
For "python manage.py test" , sys.argv=['manage.py', 'test']
So it works for both. Otherwise you can use "TESTING = True if 'test' in sys.argv[0:3] else False"

Comment: ``TESTING = 'test' in sys.argv or 'pytest' in sys.argv[0]``

Answer (score 59):

The selected answer is a massive hack. :)

A less-massive hack would be to create your own TestSuiteRunner subclass and change a setting or do whatever else you need to for the rest of your application. You specify the test runner in your settings:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'your.project.MyTestSuiteRunner'
```

In general, you don't want to do this, but it works if you absolutely need it.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner

class MyTestSuiteRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        settings.IM_IN_TEST_MODE = True
        super(MyTestSuiteRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

NOTE: As of Django 1.8, `DjangoTestSuiteRunner` has been deprecated.
You should use `DiscoverRunner` instead:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class MyTestSuiteRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        settings.IM_IN_TEST_MODE = True
        super(MyTestSuiteRunner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That should do the trick, but I'm all for simpler solutions :-)

Comment: I like this approach, but note that this code will run after your other code has been imported. So if you need to detect the condition in module-level code this won't work.

Comment: Modifying `django.conf.settings` is strongly discouraged by Django docs, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

Comment: The selected answer is a massive hack *but so is this!*

Comment: It's a massive hack I'm finding in production code here but I don't think it's particularly robust against different ways of invoking python, invoking testing and/or swapping out `manage.py test` for something such as `pytest`.

Answer (score 24):

Not quite sure about your use case but one way I've seen to detect when the test suite is running is to check if `django.core.mail` has a `outbox` attribute such as:

```
from django.core import mail

if hasattr(mail, 'outbox'):
    # We are in test mode!
    pass
else:
    # Not in test mode...
    pass
```

This attributed is added by the Django test runner in `setup_test_environment` and removed in `teardown_test_environment`. You can check the source here: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/test/utils.py

Edit: If you want models defined for testing only then you should check out [Django ticket #7835](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7835) in particular [comment #24](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7835#comment:24) part of which is given below:

> Apparently you can simply define models directly in your tests.py.
>   Syncdb never imports tests.py, so those models won't get synced to the
>   normal db, but they will get synced to the test database, and can be
>   used in tests.

Comment: It is not the usual way. But I think it'll work. I've seen this code inside django's core but I thought that it would have a more "specific" solution.

About the use case: the app I am writing uses some variations of models and form fields. So I need the models working only in test mode in order to have a good test coverage; The app is opensource and you can see it here: https://github.com/herberthamaral/django-jqgrid

Comment: Ah yes now I understand what you are asking. I've updated my answer to include handling test only models. I have a similar use case in one of my project's test suite: https://bitbucket.org/mlavin/django-selectable

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark. This is a very useful resource and I think it should go on Django's doc.

Comment: This one is a hack worse even that the accepted answer. It only works as long as you do not change your email backend.

Comment: I'll agree that this is a bit of a hack but "It only works as long as you do not change your email backend" is simply not true. Django's test suite environment always changes the email backend to use the in-memory backend which is why this works. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#email-services

Answer (score 15):

I'm using settings.py overrides. I have a global settings.py, which contains most stuff, and then I have overrides for it. Each settings file starts with:

```
from myproject.settings import settings
```

and then goes on to override some of the settings.

- prod_settings.py - Production settings (e.g. overrides DEBUG=False)
- dev_settings.py - Development settings (e.g. more logging)
- test_settings.py

And then I can define UNIT_TESTS=False in the base settings.py, and override it to UNIT_TESTS=True in test_settings.py.

Then whenever I run a command, I need to decide which settings to run against (e.g. `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.test_settings ./manage.py test`). I like that clarity.

Comment: Nice and explicit, this is how I do it as well.  You can also do DJANGO_ENV=test ./manage.py test, and pick that up with sys.env in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can just simply use environment variables in this way:

```
export MYAPP_TEST=1 && python manage.py test
```

then in your `settings.py` file:

```
import os

TEST = os.environ.get('MYAPP_TEST')

if TEST:
    # Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are lots of good answers on this page, I think there is also another way to check if your project is in the test mode or not (if in some cases you couldn't use `sys.argv[1:2] == ["test"]`).

As you all may know `DATABASE` name will change to something like "**test_***" (DATABASE default name will be prefixed with test) when you are in the test mode (or you can simply print it out to find your database name when you are running tests). Since I used pytest in one of my projects, I couldn't use

```
sys.argv[1:2] == ["test"]
```

because this argument wasn't there. So I simply used this one as my shortcut to check if I'm in the test environment or not (you know that your `DATABASE` name prefixed with **test** and if not just change **test** to your prefixed part of `DATABASE` name):

**1) Any places other than settings module**

```
from django.conf import settings

TESTING_MODE = "test" in settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]
```

**2) Inside the settings module**

```
TESTING_MODE = "test" in DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]
```

or

```
TESTING_MODE = DATABASES["default"]["NAME"].startswith("test")  # for more strict checks
```

And if this solution is doable, you don't even need to `import sys` for checking this mode inside your `settings.py` module.

Comment: Good notion, but for some databases (e.g., oracle), it should be USER rather than name, since "NAME" may be the local connection string.

Comment: I like this solution, I really do. However django users are able to change the name of the test database. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809393/specify-django-test-database-names-in-settings-py , A small change should fix this ofcourse. I've also tried the `IS_TESTING = 'test' in sys.argv` solution which is a bit easier to read. Nice out of the box solution! thats for sure : )

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me with Django 4.1.5: `IN_TEST = 'testserver' in settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Django [class based settings](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-classbasedsettings).  I use the 'switcher' from the package and load a different config/class for `testing=True`:

```
switcher.register(TestingSettings, testing=True)
```

In my configuration, I have a `BaseSettings`, `ProductionSettings`, `DevelopmentSettings`, `TestingSettings`, etc.  They subclass off of each other as needed.  In `BaseSettings` I have `IS_TESTING=False`, and then in `TestingSettings` I set it to `True`.

It works well if you keep your class inheritance clean.  But I find it works better than the `import *` method Django developers usually use.