# Django settings are not loaded when running tests

Tags: python, django, settings

I have different settings for different environments for my application, such as local, dev, stage, production. So, when I run my apps, say, locally, I pass the settings as the parameter to `manage.py`, e.g. `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 --settings=myapp.settings.local`, and indeed all my settings are correctly initialised, e.g. `DEBUG` is `True` as it is set in my settings file, and not `False` as it is in `defaultsettings.py`.

However, when I try to run tests with `python3 manage.py test --settings=myapp.settings.local`, the value of `DEBUG` is set to false, that is it is loaded from `defaultsettings.py`. Why does that happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: Check if [this is of any help](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings).

Comment: Is DEBUG the only setting affected? I'm pretty sure that the test runner automatically sets that to True anyway.

Comment: I found the same information a bit after i posted my question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that when you run your tests, all your settings are just like they are in your settings file **except for DEBUG**. `DEBUG` is always set to `False` to make the set up as close to production as possible.

I ended up following this post: [Detect django testing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957016/detect-django-testing-mode)

`import sys
TESTING = sys.argv[1:2] == ['test']`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the test you import the settings like this:
`from django.conf import settings`