# Django ignores test database settings

Tags: python, django

I have an app deployed on pythonanywhere which runs fine. Problem is that when I want to run test django, my test database settings is completely ignored.
Each time I run test I get the following message.though.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...                                                                                       
Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'funnshopp'@'%' to database 'test_funnshopp$funn'")
```

Database name for the app is `funnshopp$funn`. It can be seen that django somehow always tries to create the test database by appending `test_` to the database name. Never minding what I have in `DATABASES` settings

Below is my full settings file ( Test runs fine on my PC and I am using `Django 2.0`, though I started the project with `Django 1.11`)

```
"""
Django settings for funnshopp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


def get_env_variable(var_name):
    """Get the environment variable or return exception"""
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the {} environment variable".format(var_name)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

ENV_ROLE = get_env_variable("ENV_ROLE")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
FUNN_PASS = False
if ENV_ROLE == "development":
    DEBUG = True
    FUNN_PASS = get_env_variable('FUNN_PASS')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'asset',
    'debit',
    'communication',
    'establishment',
    'credit',
    'personnel',
    'relation',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'captcha',
    'guardian',
    'rules',
    'coverage',
    'django_extensions',
    'pure_pagination',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'django_addanother',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'rules.permissions.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'funnshopp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'funnshopp.wsgi.application'

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost')

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
        'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
]

GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY = get_env_variable("GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY")
GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY")

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('personnel:dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('personnel:login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('personnel:logout')

if ENV_ROLE == "development":
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
else:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '***@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '***@gmail.com'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DEPLOYMENT_PLATFORM = get_env_variable("DEPLOYMENT_PLATFORM")
if DEPLOYMENT_PLATFORM == "heroku-plus-local":
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'funn',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('FUNN_PASS'),
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': 5432
        }
    }

else: # DEPLOYMENT_PLATFORM == "pythonanywhere"
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'USER': 'funnshopp',
            'NAME': 'funnshopp$funn',
            'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('FUNN_PASS'),
            'HOST': 'funnshopp.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
            'TEST':{
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # for sqlite3
                'NAME':'test.db',
                # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                # 'NAME':'funnshopp$test_default'
                },
            },
        }

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Lagos'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'personnel.Person'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Below is the result of `pip freeze`

```
alabaster==0.7.10                                                                                                                   
Babel==2.5.1                                                                                                                        
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0                                                                                                               
certifi==2017.11.5                                                                                                                  
chardet==3.0.4                                                                                                                      
colorama==0.3.9                                                                                                                     
coverage==4.4.2                                                                                                                     
dj-database-url==0.4.2                                                                                                              
dj-static==0.0.6                                                                                                                    
Django==2.0.1                                                                                                                       
django-addanother==2.0.0                                                                                                            
django-archive==0.1.5                                                                                                               
django-braces==1.12.0                                                                                                               
django-debug-toolbar==1.9.1                                                                                                         
django-extensions==1.9.9                                                                                                            
django-guardian==1.4.9                                                                                                              
django-heroku==0.2.0                                                                                                                
django-pure-pagination==0.3.0                                                                                                       
django-recaptcha==1.3.1                                                                                                             
django-toolbelt==0.0.1                                                                                                              
django-webtest==1.9.2                                                                                                               
docutils==0.14                                                                                                                      
funcsigs==1.0.2                                                                                                                     
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
```

Comment: this fails with Django version 2.0.1? what if you try using `TEST_NAME` key instead of `TEST` dictionary like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809717/1527018

Comment: From the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#test. `TEST_NAME` is for older versions.

Comment: yeah that is why i am asking what version you are using

Comment: 2.0.1 as you can see from my 'pip freeze' output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by reorganizing my settings file according to the pattern suggested here [Recommended Django Project Layout](https://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/).

Now my test runs fine on pythonanywhere.

Btw, I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Parousiaic/89b04ebef8617805b8b94509d5762f15) here which deals with the problems of virtual environments and layouts and how to handle virtual environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common and correct behavior. Django when testing will always try to create new database, and you should never try to test you application on your live/production database.

Your tests should be constructed in a way, where you create your objects and then test their behavior. You are using postgres, on heroku and mysql on development server. If you want to use this databases to test you app, you have to add django user to you postgres/mysql with rights to create and delete databases/tables.

You can also avoid this by adding this setting to your settings.py (this is what I like to do when I do not use any other extensions and sqlite3 database is just enough. I run my tests by typing `python manage.py test`

```
if any([arg in sys.argv for arg in ['jenkins', 'test']]):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        }
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Comment: If you could ready carefully my answer I think you will find all the answers needed :)

Comment: Often, @mic4ael, someone will come with a question similar to "how do I best use christmas pudding to hammer in a nail".  An answer to the question might be "bake it until it is solid", but a better answer is "use a hammer".  In this case, sebb has answered in the second manner, as he is correct - one should not run tests against the production database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change how you format your settings.py, you must not put if conditions inside it but use different settings based on the environment you are working on!

I recommend you to read this [tutorial](https://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/).

When you have the proper layout you can change the database in the different settings file ;)!

Comment: Thanks for that point. I'll read the tutorial and implement such

Comment: @Parousia Happy to being helpful, if it works mark the answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you know, when you are running tests, Django isolates the changes made to the database. That is why it tries to create a database which is denied by the DB engine. You can either:

1. Create a database, grant access to the user and use `--keepdb` to run the tests
2. Or grant access to the DB user to create a database. Something like:

   `ALTER USER username CREATEDB;`